# What is this white flowered purslane lookalike from South Florida?

Tags: identification, succulents, herbs, wildflowers

My wife found some purslane on her daily walk and brought some home for the garden. We also have another weed growing in the backyard that seems to be purslane as well, but it lacks branching stems and the stems seems to be all green. I would like help to identify it.

[image: flower]

Comment: Hi Menachem! I see you've been around the network a bit and want to welcome you to this site! Where do you live? Is this pretty flower in the sun or shade? It looks like a spreading groundcover about the height of the other purslane that you're sure of. Is that correct? Someone around here will probably know what that is. In the meantime, any more details you can add would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I'm in south Florida. The flower is in partial shade and low drainage soil, but spreading to higher ground. The lawnmower doesn't really do anything to it. The stems seems to be a continual runner. I can't find where it begins and they crisscross everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be [waterhyssop, *Bacopa monnieri*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacopa_monnieri). It is a medicinal herb of warm climate wetlands. Makes sense that it was growing in poorly drained soil.

Photo courtesy of Wikipedia:

[image]